# SVG's animate href not working in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, svg, href, svg-animate

Recently was surfing about SVG's animate tags, and saw something like this:

```html
<svg><animate href="#x" attributeName="href" values="https://www.google.com"/><a id="x"><circle r=100>
```

So, this will insert the `<animate values>` into the `<a>` tag as `href` while rendering. So, when you click the circle animation, https://www.google.com is triggered.

The issue is, this href insertion doesn't work in Firefox. Works well in Chrome.

1. How do I achieve this "values" insertion into `<a>` tag in Firefox? (The question is to achieve the *dynamic insertion* using SVG and not about the functionality)
2. Else, are there any similar *runtime attribute insertion* feature in SVG that is supported in Firefox? What are they? I need to specifically inject some value to `<a>'s href` attribute without directly specifying it.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a Firefox bug here:

I need to add a dummy href="" on the `<a>` element to get it working.

I've raised [a bug on Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1362400) and attached a patch that fixes the bug.

```html
<svg><animate href="#x"
attributeName="href" 
values="https://www.google.com"/><a href="" id="x"><circle r="100"/>
</a></svg>
```

If I do it the old fashioned xlink:href way I need a dummy xlink:href value instead.

```html
<svg><animate href="#x"
attributeName="xlink:href" 
values="https://www.google.com"/><a xlink:href="" id="x"><circle r="100"/>
</a></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This make the `circle` clickable with the link, but Chrome seems to insert the link into the `<a>'s href`, but FF doesn't. Can we make FF to insert the `values` in `<a>'s href` just like Chrome? I need specifically insert the `values` into `<a>'s href` at run time.

Comment: Works at runtime for me i.e. Clicking on the link takes you to the animated location

Comment: Yeah, but Chrome differs in it. I specifically speak about the DOM, where in Chrome, the link is inserted into the `<a>'s href`, but not in Firefox. I'm kinda working with DOM parsing-related, so can you please suggest me some way to dynamically insert the `values` link to `<a>'s href`?

Comment: You can read the animVal using the SVG DOM just fine on Firefox. It won't show if you use getAttribute though.

Comment: animVal is not exactly same as the `<a>'s href` at some cases in Chrome. For example, if the link is `&#8192;https://www.google.com`, Chrome's SVG renderer will strip out (trim) the `&#8192;` and insert only `https://www.google.com` into `<a>'s href`. But, FF doesn't trim and dynamically insert  it in `<a>'s href` and has untrimmed values in animVal. I couldn't explain exactly the use case, but, I need the trimmed value i.e., `https://www.google.com` without `&#8192;` (just like Chrome does) automatically while rendering in `<a>'s href`.

Comment: Any possibility to make it work (trim and dynamic run-time `href` insertion automagically just like Chrome? I mean with any other feature of SVG?

Comment: Sure, download the source code to Firefox and fix it.

Comment: @RobertLongson if you have a free time, can you take a look on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43618372/5875416) please? thanks.